# std::bind a thread memeber variable to an instance of a class

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

I am confused between the various ways I can create member threads to run on member functions of a class instance and what are the differences between all of them :-
First method - using lambda expressions

```
auto m_thread = std::thread([this]{run();});
```

Second method

```
auto m_thread = std::thread(std::bind(&MyType::run, this));
```

Third method

```
auto res = std::bind(&m_thread, std::bind(&MyType::run, this));
```

Fourth method -

```
auto res = std::bind(&m_thread, &MyType::run, this);
```

Here,
m_thread is a member variable of a Class **MyType** given by `std::thread m_thread` of which `this` is an instance and run is a member function of the same class. Will all of these give the same results and are they equivalent? Also, in the last two cases how to make the thread start executing.

Comment: First argument of `std::bind` should be a callable (and copyable) (but indeed not done with SFINAE), `std::thread` is neither.

Comment: There is also, simply, `auto m_thread = std::thread(&MyType::run, this);`.

Comment: Then indeed, they are several way to transform a callable in another callable (and potentially binding some parameter).

Comment: @Jarod42 So, in essence, the last two methods don't work. The first two methods are equivalent . Am I correct?

Comment: In short, yes..

Comment: @abhiverma -- the first two are equivalent in the sense that they mean the same thing. They are not equivalent in that the second one adds unnecessary overhead. `std::thread` does the bind internally so you don't need to do it yourself. In fact, the simplest way to write this is `std::thread m_thread(&MyType::run, this);`. (Yes, I know, "always auto"; do it that way if you must)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::bind` expects a callable at first argument (but doesn't reject invalid arguments).

So 3rd and 4th method create unusable objects.

To create the `std::thread`, you have indeed several available variant:

- `std::thread(&MyType::run, this);`
- `std::thread(std::bind(&MyType::run, this));` No advantages from above.
- `std::thread([this](){ return this->run(); );` Allows to handle `run` overloads, default parameters.

Comment: How come you're not using `std::men_fn()` in the first two options?

Comment: @einpoklum Can you elaborate upon it ?

Comment: @abhiverma `mem_fn` gains nothing over the plain member function pointer; `std::thread` can handle the case implicitly.